# An equation involving multisets

Tags: set-theory, type-theory, multiset

For finite multisets $A, B, C, A', B', C'$, if $A \uplus B \uplus \{B \uplus C\} \uplus \{A \uplus \{C\}\}$ = $A' \uplus B' \uplus \{B' \uplus C'\} \uplus \{A' \uplus \{C'\}\}$, must $A=A',B=B',C=C'$, where $\uplus$ denotes mutliset sum as defined here https://oeis.org/wiki/Multisets#Multiset_sum

EDIT: Here's why I'm interested in this question. In simply relationally typed higher-order languages following Orey "Model Theory for the Higher Order Predicate Calculus" (1959), predicates have different syntactic types, which are identified with sequences of types. The idea is that, if a predicate is of type $\langle t_1,\dots,t_n\rangle$, then it combines with $n$ arguments respectively of types $t_1,\dots,t_n$ in that order to form a formula. I'm interested in how to think about higher-order languages like this except where, intuitively, the argument-places of predicates are unordered; to form a formula by combining a predicate with some arguments you can't just list the arguments -- instead (simplifying somewhat) you biject arguments with argument-places of the predicate. In this framework, types of predicates aren't identified with sequences of types, but with multisets of types, since multisets are basically unordered sequences.

The reason I'm interested in the particular equation above is that, in thinking about how to do combinatory logic in such a higher-order language, it turns out that the analogue of what are usually called B combinators end up having types of the above form, and I'm interested in whether these combinators, in this setting, are uniquely determined by their types, or whether there could be distinct B-like combinators of the same type. (Intuitively, such a combinator of type $A \uplus B \uplus \{B \uplus C\} \uplus \{A \uplus \{C\}\}$ can combine with arguments $a_1,...,a_n$ the multiplicity of the types of which is $A$, $b_1,...,b_m$ the multiplicity of the types of which is $B$, a predicate of type $\{B \uplus C\}$, and a predicate of type $\{A \uplus \{C\}\}$ to form a formula. For example, if $A=B=C=\{e\}$ (where $e$ is the base type of individuals), the relevant B-like combinator will be analogous to the simply relationally-typed lambda-term $\beta := (\lambda x^ey^eX^{\langle e,e\rangle}Y^{\langle e,\langle e\rangle\rangle}.Yx(\lambda z^e.Xyz))$, which combines with terms $a$ and $b$ of type $e$, a predicate $R$ of type $\langle e,e\rangle$, and a predicate $S$ of type $\langle e, \langle e\rangle\rangle$, to form a formula $\beta abRS$ which we can think of as saying that individual $a$ stands in relation $S$ to the property of being $R$-related to individual $b$.)

Maybe this is still too random a question to count as research-level for the purposes of this site, but I thought I'd add this explanation to indicate that it is at least a question that arose in the course of research, and isn't just a homework assignment or something.

Comment: original post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325619/an-equation-involving-multisets without success

Comment: What kinds of things are you allowing as elements of multisets? Also are they necessarily well-founded? I imagine the answer to your question is no if you allow ill-founded multisets.

Comment: Let’s allow them to have urelements as members. They should definitely well-founded — we can think of them as functions whose co-domains are sets of cardinals. If it makes it easier, we can restrict our attention to multisets with finite multiplicity, which we can represent as functions onto the natural numbers.

Comment: I see two possible notions of union here: disjoint union and what I will call tagged union. Tagged union means each multiset member gets a tag, and then one setunions the sets of tags. One has to tag properly to get a sensible result. Disjoint union means every member gets their own unique tag, and then do tagged union. What form of union do you intend? Gerhard "And Are There Union Dues?" Paseman, 2019.09.02.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken about the appropriate terminology for this! I'll edited the question now to clarify. Using the terminology from wikipedia, I mean the notion they call "Sum" (the generalization of disjoint union to multisets) rather than the notion they call "Union"; so, for example, $\{a\}\cup \{a\} = \{a,a\}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: (changed to $\uplus$ in the question, but can't edit comment)

Comment: For finite multisets, this is likely to hold, using an induction argument on something like rank. For infinite sets, there may be counterexamples, especially among non well-founded sets. If you specify finite in the problem, I will answer with a proposal of how to prove it. Warning: the proposal may fail, as I have a feeling the restricted version is true, but no proof. Gerhard "Have A Stick Of Dynamite" Paseman, 2019.09.02.

Comment: Just edited to add restriction to finite multisets

Comment: In case I don't get around to it later, here is the idea. Let rank be a function on finite multisets, where rank of the empty set is zero and otherwise is 1 + Max of ranks of members of the set. The set produced has rank greater than any of A B and C, and one of the last two members has maximal rank. Use this to analyze cases, and find where the challenging bits are.  Gerhard "More A Proposal Than Proof" Paseman, 2019.09.02.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98225/discussion-between-jeremy-and-gerhard-paseman).